# How can I switch Google back to the white background instead of the image?

Tags: google-search

Recently my Google home page starting having a background image. I like the plain white background. How can I switch back to the white background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bottom left of your google page you should see the following link: `Remove background image`

Comment: the problem with that link is that its white and so it was not visible on the image that i had choosed, silly google :)

Answer (score 2):

In the bottom left corner, just click the link! "Remove background image"